# How to select only one li element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be an easy fix but I just can't wrap my head around javascript selectors just yet. I have a list of h3 li elements that each contain content that is shown on click. I want a toggle arrow to change from up to down on click. But with the JS code below this happens for all li elements including the one for which the collapsed content is not showing. How can I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#toggle-view li').click(function () {
    var text = $(this).children('div.panel');
    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        $("h3 .fa-caret-up").removeClass("fa-caret-up").addClass("fa-caret-down");
    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        $("h3 .fa-caret-down").removeClass("fa-caret-down").addClass("fa-caret-up");
    }

});
});
```

Here is the html in case you need it:

```
<ul class="services-ul facebook-ul" id="toggle-view">
        <li>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 1<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></h3>
                <span>+</span>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>dummy text...</p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 2<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></h3>
                <span>+</span>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>dummy text...</p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 3<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></h3>
                <span>+</span>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>dummy text...</p>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h3><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Header 4<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></h3>
                <span>+</span>
                <div class="panel">
                    <p>dummy text...</p>
                </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the elements relative to `this` (which within your `click` event is the `li` element which has been clicked on).

Simply wrap `this` in a jQuery selector (`$(this)`), then use [jQuery's `find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the elements contained within it:

```
$(this).find('.fa-caret-up').removeClass('.fa-caret-up').addClass('.fa-caret-down');
```

And:

```
$(this).find('.fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
```

Comment: Works great. Please note that you have two dots in the first line of code before .removeClass and .addClass that I needed to remove.